# Can I communicate with my local test net via REST/WebAPI

Tags: cardano-cli, cardano-graphql, cardano-api, typescript

I am using this https://github.com/woofpool/cardano-private-testnet-setup to run my local testnet.

I was using this

```
const CardanocliJs = require('cardanocli-js');
const cardano = new CardanocliJs(options);
const txinds = cardano.queryUtxo(walletAddress);
```

But now I want my script to run on a different machine than the node and because cardanocli-js use cardano-cli and cardano-cli use cardano-node it's impossible

Note:
The script and the machine will not keep any private keys. The script will generate transactions based on some parameters.

In most protocols, Nodes have rest api, but I can't find anything like that in cardano.

Should I start this on the same machine as Cardano node in order to achieve my goal? https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-graphql

Or maybe some other tool from the cardano ecosystem?